# how to determine the average biterate and peak bitrate of a video using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I don't understand, when in ffmpeg i do `ffmpeg -i <input>` i have :

> Video: hevc (Main) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p(tv), 1920x1080, 4997 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 998795.00 tbn, 30 tbc (default)

it's show bitrate: **4997 kb/s** BUT the size of the file is **114915563 bytes** for a duration of **179 secondes**. when i do math i have 114915563 / 179 = 641986 bytes/s = **642 kb/s** :(

What did i miss ? how to retrieve the average bitrate of a movie and the peak bitrate of a movie ?

Comment: It's 642 k **B** /s. Multiply by 8 for total kb/s. And it's for the total file i.e. + audio + overhead.

Comment: aaah ok ! tss better to write kbps than kb/s it's confusing :( and you know how to retrieve the peak bitrate ?